# why does blank hashmap return null value

Tags: java

```
 Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
 System.out.println(map.get("abc"));
```

above case return `null`. Shouldn't it be returning `Null Pointer Exception`. I was expecting NPP because there is no such key "abc" in it. Why has it returned `null`.  Can anyone clear away my doubts..

Comment: Did you read the Javadoc of the get method? `Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key. `

Comment: ok, .. reading..

Comment: Just press Ctrl+Q on `get` method, you will get your answer.

Answer (score 2):

`NPE` occours when you want to invoke members of an object which is null. Here `NPE` will occur if you do like below:

```
System.out.println(map.get("abc").length());
```

Because `map.get("abc")` returns `null` and you are trying to do `null.length()`